# typedef struct vs. Object - Benefits

Tags: ios, objective-c, struct

I plan to define a class, that among its properties contains coordinates for an x/y grid.  However, I'm unsure of the 'best' way to approach the design of this.  It's a very simple issue, I just want to do it correctly and have a justification!

One solution would be to have to two properties, of type '`int`', one for x and one for y, within the object.

The other would be define a typedef struct of two ints containing x/y values and naming it `<ClassPrefix>Coordinate`.  Similar to `CGSize`?

Are there any other/better ways to do this?  Which is preferred?  Not sure how to justify either way.

Thanks!

Tim.

Comment: why don't you simply use `CGPoint` for that?

Comment: I considered CGPoint but I figured that's for x/y coordinates within a UIView, not within my own bespoke grid system, so would it not be misusing a Core Graphics value? If not... then this is a bit of a non-question!

Comment: `CGPoint` is just a struct, so you can use it the way you like without really "messing" things in CG. A good thing would be `typedef CGPoint MyOwnPointType` to have it behave as your own type and avoid mixed uses.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will go for the typedef on CGPoint approach, just to differentiate between CG and my own uses.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer to the "Which one is preferred?" question depends on a few factors:

- **How many items like this you plan to create?** - If the answer is "millions", `struct` wins; if the answer is "fifty eight", object wins.
- **Do you need to define methods on it?** - If the answer is "yes", object wins; otherwise, `struct` may be OK.
- **Do you plan to define arrays of it?** - If the answer is "yes", `struct` may be a better choice.
- **Do you need to create and destroy it often?** - If the answer is "yes", `struct` may be a better choice.

Ultimately, your design constraints help you determine what's best; there is no data structure that is universally "better".

Comment: Great answer. I will be defining arrays of these grid items, there may not be millions, but considerably more than 100!  I did think that using a struct could be more beneficial from a performance perspective.  Based on sergio's comment, I will define a typedef on CGPoint.

Comment: @Tim Since `CGPoint` uses `double`s and you need `int`s, I would avoid "marrying" the two, and define my own struct. This would let you avoid trouble in cases when you externalize your `struct` (say, save it to a file, or sent via network), because it would protect you from the changes that Apple might want to make behind your back. Of course if it does not matter to you, and your struct represents points in a range that fits in `CGFloat` anyway, then you might reuse `CGPoint` "wholesale" without your own `typedef`, because in most cases `typedef` does not provide enough "insulation".

Comment: Not sure if "Do you plan to define arrays of it?" is a good question. Both arrays of structs and arrays of objects are widely used.

Comment: @Sulthan That is definitely true, but arrays of `struct`s tend to be more compact, can be defined in the automatic memory (i.e. on the stack), and are much cheaper to copy. For sure, it's not a clear-cut decision, that's why I wrote "may be a better choice", as opposed to "are a better choice".

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @dasblinkenlight answer, I'll give you some decision advices:

- **Is the structure immutable after creation**?
   Use an object.
- **Does the structure owns (= retains) pointers to other objects or arrays (both C arrays or `NSArray`)? Does it interact with objects (= has methods with object parameters)?**
   Then use an object.
- **Does the structure contains only primitive types (`int`, `float`, other `struct`s etc) and it interacts only with other primitives/structs?**
   Then use a `struct` with functions.

Comment: Thanks, this confirms a struct is definitely what I should be going for.  Although, if it was immutable after creation, surely a struct is best, not an object as above?

Comment: @Tim There is no way to ensure immutability of an `struct`, therefore when immutability is required, you have to go for an object.

Answer (score 1):

It is a trade off.

A class and its instances will cost more in resource, especially when you have to make a lot of them. If there will not be so many instances, it is not a problem.

Structure is faster but it's difficult to extent and the most inconvenient thing is a struct can not hold objects or method.

For your example, if you just use it for coordinates, I suggest you to use struct. But it depends on your design and code. There is no absolute judgment which is best.